# Cannot resize tab control in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I cannot resize the tab control in Access 2016. It is currently about 16 inches wide, and I need to make it 14 inches. I typed 14" in the Width property of the property window, but it resizes back to the original 16 inches. Would appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Howard Hong

Comment: Must be 1 or more controls on the tab control that extend beyond the 14". Could be a line.

Answer (score 1):

I guess one of the other tabs have controls exceeding the 14". Check them.